# Rspec: How to capture the examples, Failures and pending Count

Tags: ruby, rspec

Well i am trying to achieve one thing.  Something fancy but worth trying..

When i run `bundle exec rspec spec/`

My test cases pass and i get

```
Finished in 5.12 seconds
38 examples, 0 failures, 1 pending
```

I want to use the MAC OS `say` command (Read [here](http://www.gabrielserafini.com/blog/2008/08/19/mac-os-x-voices-for-using-with-the-say-command/) about it).  Which will say after the test suite has completed, that `you have 38 examples, 0 failures and 1 pending example`.

eg command

`say you have example_count examples, failures_count failures and pending_count pending examples`

The requirement is, I need to capture Examples, Failures and pending in a variable which i can use with `say` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write custom RSpec formatter and do your magic there. You can also have multiple formatters.

Check this resources for more information:

- [Custom formatters (Relish)](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/formatters/custom-formatters)
- [How to Use Multiple Formatters in RSpec 2](http://itreallymatters.net/post/1592879361/how-to-use-multiple-formatters-in-rspec-2#.UUBHfdH45DI)
- [Source code base_text_formatter.rb](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/formatters/base_text_formatter.rb)