# How to capture rspec examples, passed, failed count to a variable and return to console?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I need to capture the examples pass, fail count which rspec displays at the nd of the test run to a variable and return to console.

```
Finished in 30 minutes 2.79 seconds
12 examples, 0 failures
```

Request to please guide me on this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381037/rspec-how-to-capture-the-examples-failures-and-pending-count?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you can capture a script's output.

The simplest is to run the script in backticks from ruby:

```
results = `rspec`
#=> "Blah, blah, blah\nFinished in 30 minutes 2.79 seconds\n12 examples, 0 failures\n"
```

The downside of this is that the script will *not* output to the console as it runs, and if you have some tests that are taking half an hour to run, you probably want to keep an eye on them.

With this in mind, you could use `Open3` instead:

```
require 'open3'
result = ''
Open3.popen2e('rspec') do |stdin, stdout_err, wait_thr|
  while (line = stdout_err.gets) # this captures each line as it goes
    puts line
    result << line
  end
end

result
#=> "Blah, blah, blah\nFinished in 30 minutes 2.79 seconds\n12 examples, 0 failures\n"
```

If you need to print out character-by-character, use `getc` instead of `gets` and `print` instead of `puts`. If you also want to print in colour, you'll need to use `PTY` instead of `Open3`:

```
require 'pty'
result = ''
PTY.spawn('rspec') do |stdout_err, stdin, pid|
  begin
    while (char = stdout_err.getc)
      print char
      result << char
    end
  rescue Errno::EIO # PTY raises this when the stream closes
  ensure
    Process.waitpid pid # Wait for `rspec` to finish before continuing
  end
end

result
#=> "Blah, blah, blah\nFinished in 30 minutes 2.79 seconds\n12 examples, 0 failures\n"
```

Either way, you would then be able to use a regular expression to pull the values out:

```
match_data = result.match(/(\d+) examples, (\d+) failures/)
#=> #<MatchData "12 examples, 0 failures" 1:"12" 2:"0">

examples = match_data[1]
#=> "12"

fails = match_data[2]
#=> "0"
```